# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference even if object is initialized

Tags: java, android

```
scheduleClient = new ScheduleClient(mContext);
scheduleClient.doBindService();
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
scheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(cal);
```

I can't see where is the problem as I have initialized the object. Rhis is the error which I am getting.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void lol.com.epl.ScheduleService.setAlarm(java.util.Calendar)' on a null object reference
        at lol.com.epl.ScheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(ScheduleClient.java:63)
        at lol.com.epl.FixAdapter$1.onClick(FixAdapter.java:128)
```

java:128 points to line

```
scheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(cal);
```

At line 63

```
  public void setAlarmForNotification(Calendar c){

    mBoundService.setAlarm(c);
}
```

Comment: Something is null at line 63 of `ScheduleClient`, inside the `setAlarmForNotification` method.

Comment: Can you add scheduleclient.java code especially the line 63

Comment: i have edited@Materazzi06

Comment: Looks like mBoundService is null.